# Javafx CSS Some Properties Not Working

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am having trouble making it so that my `nameInput` label and `passInput` label are bolded. My program allows me to do a `-fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;` and that works but when i try `-fx-font-weight: bold;` it wont work or bold my label when the app runs.

Here is my code containing my labels and buttons:

```
package appGUI;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class Login extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Button loginButton;
    String user = "test";
    String pw = "test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);       
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Secret");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        grid.setVgap(8);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        // name label
        Label nameLabel = new Label("Enter your name:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(nameLabel, 0, 0);

        // name input
        TextField nameInput = new TextField();
        nameInput.setPromptText("name");
        GridPane.setConstraints(nameInput, 1, 0);

        // password label
        Label passLabel = new Label("Enter the password:");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passLabel, 0, 1);

        // password input
        PasswordField passInput = new PasswordField();
        passInput.setPromptText("password");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passInput, 1, 1);

        // login button
        loginButton = new Button("Enter");
        GridPane.setConstraints(loginButton, 1, 2);
        loginButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(nameInput.getText().equals(user) && passInput.getText().equals(pw)) {
                System.out.println("THIS WORKS. YOU FINALLY SOLVED IT!!!!");
          } else {
                AlertBox.display("Error: Access Denied", "Only a special person can access this app");
            }

        });

        grid.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, nameInput, passLabel, passInput, loginButton); 

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 350, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/appGUI/custom.css");

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

    }
}
```

And here is the .css file titled "custom.css" that works properly and does everything I wrote except for bold text:

```
.root {
   -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#707070, #BABABA); 
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;  
}

.button {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#00F5FF, #FFA07A);
    -fx-background-radius:10;
}
```

I have tried almost everything and I can't seem to find the answer to what seems like a really easy problem to fix. My labels just wont bold, but they'll fill with `#FFFFFF`, and i just want to know why one property works and the other one doesn't!

Comment: It simply works, nothing is wrong. Try with "bolder".

Comment: have the same problem using FXForms2 generated forms. Some properties work, some don't. In my case, Size and Italic works ok, while text-fill color doesnt...

Answer (score 5):

For some strange reason the default font not necessarily supports all features.

Try:

```
.label {
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you want to make this change application wide, add it to the scene:

```
.root {
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
}

scene.getStylesheets().add("pathTo/root.css");
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem (on MacOS) and "Helvetica" does not help either. With "Arial" it is now working. CSS in JavaFx seems even more black-magic than for the web.

Comment: Dear Jörg, what JavaFx version are you using? Helvetica did work well for me on Mac with Java 8.

Comment: I am using OpenJFX version 14.0.1.